# How can I find all files in a directory that are either empty, or only contain whitespace?

Tags: linux, bash, find

Is there a simple way to find all files in a directory that only contain whitespace? `find -empty` only finds truly empty files, but I'd also like to find files that only contain spaces, newlines, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This command will do it nicely:

```
find . -type f ! -exec grep -q '[^[:space:]]' {} \; -print
```